# Is it possible for an Element to back reference its generic Container? (Swift)

Tags: swift, oop, generics

### Example II

The original example is inappropriate, as some people have pointed out (I agree now, thanks). So I come up with a new one, a more complicated one. By the way, I will really appreciate if you can help me to understand this at a more abstract level.

```
class Employee {
    var department :Department? = nil

    func leader() -> Employee {
       return self.department!.director
    }
}

class Designer :Employee {
    func design() {
        // Draw some blueprint
    }
}

class Developer :Employee {
    func develop() {
        // Write some code
    }
}

class Department <E: Employee> {
    let employees :[E]
    let director :E

    init(employees :[E], director :E) {
        self.employees = employees
        self.director = director
        for e in self.employees {
            e.department = self
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

### Example I

I am implementing something like a card game.

```
class Suit <C :Card> {
    public let cards :[C]

    init(cards :[C]) {
        self.cards = cards
    }

    convenience
    init() {
        self.init(cards: Array(1...13).map({ C(faceValue:$0) }))
        for card in self.cards {
            card.suit = self
        }
    }
}

class Card {
    public let faceValue :UInt
    public internal(set) var suit :Suit? = nil

    required
    init(faceValue :UInt) {
        self.faceValue = faceValue
    }
}
```

I want every Card has a reference back to the Suit which it belongs to.
The issue that I am facing is that the Suit is a generic class.
So, I am having this error:

[image: The error I am suffering from]

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks

Comment: 0.02 -> I think it might be a hint that your OOD is a bit off. `Deck`s have `Card`s, `Card`s have `Suit`s and `Value`s. This would be the first time I've seen someone design a `Suit` this way (just MHO).

Comment: If I used Deck to be the container, the problem would still be there. It is not about Suit, Card or Deck. It is about Element, Container and Back Reference.

Comment: That would be the first time I saw that as well. Maybe it's a matter of the game you're playing with these cards but not everything needs to know about everything else. I can design a deck of cards and not a single card would need to know about the deck it belongs to. Anyhow, good luck.

Comment: Do you really have to make `Suit` a generic class? Are there different card types (i.e. subclass of `Card`) that it will specialize it to? Or there are just `Card`s with different values?

Comment: I think you are right. This requirement doesn't really exist. But how to understand this at a more abstract level?

Comment: Much better example! I'm a newborn with swift so I don't know the details of the language but I still think your problems may be due to a < great design; should it really be the `Department`s responsibility to set itself in the `Employee`?. I'm able to remove the questionable parts and get it working by understanding a department exists prior to the employees of it so, `e.department = d` and `d.employees.append(e)` (and similar) seem to work for the design I would choose. You obviously have the department prior to sending it the employees so set it beforehand (MO).

Comment: No matter where I did the assignment, it refused working. `anEmployee.deparment` only accepts `Department<Employee>`. But `Department<Employee>` is kind of abstract. I tried to convert `Department<Developer>` to `Department<Employee>` with key key word `as`, but Swift tells me that the two types are UNRELATED (how can they be unrelated?). I believe this is a feature unsupported by Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is partly polymorphic, partly generic.  To get it to work, separate the generic part (the department and what it can contain) and the polymorphic part (the Employee class hierarchy).

**Quick Fix**

```
// A protocol to define what the department can hold:

protocol Employable {
    weak var department :Department<Self>? { get set }
}

// A generic department to hold objects that conform to the Employable protocol:

class Department <E: Employable> {
    let employees :[E]
    let director :E

    init(employees :[E], director :E) {
        self.employees = employees
        self.director = director
        for var e in self.employees {
            // e is defined as var rather than defaulting to let
            e.department = self
        }
    }
}

// The polymorphic Employee hierarchy:

class Employee : Employable {
    weak internal var department: Department<Employee>?

    func leader() -> Employee {
        return self.department!.director
    }
}

class Designer :Employee {}

class Developer :Employee {}
```

This gets your example to work, but now you can take it a step further.

**With a generic collection**

Rename Employable and Department to something generic:

```
protocol MyCollectable {
    weak var collection :MyCollection<Self>? { get set }
}

class MyCollection <E: MyCollectable> {
    let members :[E]
    let leader :E

    init(members :[E], leader :E) {
        self.members = members
        self.leader = leader
        for var e in self.members{
            e.collection = self
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
class Employee : MyCollectable {
    weak internal var collection: MyCollection<Employee>?

    func leader() -> Employee {
        return self.collection!.leader
    }
}

class Designer :Employee {}
class Developer :Employee {}

var department = MyCollection<Employee>(members: [Designer()], leader: Designer())
```

and this:

```
class Canine : MyCollectable {
    weak internal var collection: MyCollection<Canine>?
}

class Wolf : Canine {}
class Dog : Canine {}

var pack = MyCollection<Canine>(members: [Wolf(),Dog()],leader: Wolf())
var wolfPack = MyCollection<Wolf>(members: [Wolf(),Wolf()], leader: Wolf())
```

But you're protected against this:

```
var wolfPack = MyCollection<Wolf>(members: [Wolf(),Dog()], leader: Wolf())
```

Or this:

```
var wolfPack = MyCollection<Wolf>(members: [Wolf(),Designer()], leader: Wolf())
```

**UPDATE**

**Alternative using protocols for both collection and collectable**

```
protocol MyCollectable {
    associatedtype MyCollection
    var collection :MyCollection? { get set }
}

protocol MyCollection {
    associatedtype MyCollectable
    var members:[MyCollectable] { get }
    var leader:MyCollectable { get }
}

class Employee : MyCollectable {
    typealias MyCollection = Department
    internal var collection: Department?
}

class Department : MyCollection {
    typealias MyCollectable = Employee
    let members :[MyCollectable]
    let leader :MyCollectable

    init(members :[MyCollectable], leader :MyCollectable) {
        self.members = members
        self.leader = leader
        for e in self.members{
            e.collection = self
        }
    }
}

class Designer:Employee {}
class Developer:Employee {}
var dept = Department(members: [Designer(), Designer()],leader: Developer())
```

Finally, be warned that back-references are a bad idea unless the object is managed, e.g. by being stored by Core Data where the back reference is an inverse relationship.

Comment: I am really excited and inspired by this solution. However, I wondered if I can substitute another `protocol` for the settled concrete `class` on `MyCollectable.collection`. I tried with `associatedtype` but failed. So, I guess this is the best of what we can have currently.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative using protocols and associatedtype

Comment: I was failed because the `associatedtype` solution can't provide a strict type checking. Something like this will be possible `var chaos = Department(members: [Developer(), Designer()], leader: Employee())`. But, still, this is cool.

Comment: True.  With C++ you would make Employee an abstract class.  Swift doesn't have abstract classes, you'd have to make Employee a protocol too.  But then you lose the superclass abilities.